# Database created empty when models are in a separate file?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am reading a book about flask development, and I'm pretty new to python generally.

File layout:

```
Project
|
|-- App
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|
| main.py
```

Code inside `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from config import options

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():   
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'database_test.sqlite')

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
            print("DB created")

    return(app)
```

I have been researching other people's issues on the site, mostly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008260/pythonic-way-to-correctly-separate-model-from-application-using-sqlalchemy) where I found to use the `with app.app_context()`, and to instantiate the db without using `app` as part of the constructor.

Here is my `models.py` file:

```
from . import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    personaname = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False)
    steamid = db.Column(db.String(64))
    avatar = db.Column(db.String(200))
    profileurl = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_personaname_real = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {0}>'.format(self.personaname)
```

I then rune the code from `main.py` which is just:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

If I move the `User` class into the `__init__.py` function, everything is created fine. However, when the `User` class is inside it's own file, the database is created empty. I have tried using other ways of importing, maybe something like `From app.__init__.py Import db`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to import your models. The classes aren't created, and as a result not registered with SQLAlchemy, until you do.

Comment: I tried adding `from . import models` to the import lists in `__init__.py`, but now It gave these errors: [here](http://i.imgur.com/7rw97rn.jpg)

I know I imported wrong but how should I import the models?

Comment: plus if you look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008260/pythonic-way-to-correctly-separate-model-from-application-using-sqlalchemy) stack overflow question, the answer did not require importing the models, unless I'm looking wrong?

Comment: You have a circular import. `__init__` is importing your models, which import db, before db is combined. Define db before the import.

Comment: That question already had the models imported so it required a different answer.

Comment: When were the models imported in the answer that I linked? I can't tell...

Comment: `import Model, API`. That's in the same file as `main`, which is what calls `db.create_all()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since defining your model directly in `__init__.py` works, it follows that you need to import your model(s) into `__init__.py`.

You can add an import in `__init__.py` *after* you create an `SQLAlchemy` object:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
from .models import User
```

This works, but it feels horribly wrong and dirty to me. I don't know Flask that well, but this answer suggests that this is normal for Flask: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19008403/21945

Comment: There are a few common application layouts. Some require things like this to avoid circular imports. Some don't. The OP's layout falls into the former.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

How and when were the models imported in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008260/pythonic-way-to-correctly-separate-model-from-application-using-sqlalchemy) answer? Because as far as I can see, theirs ended up working fine without having to import after the instantiation of db.

Comment: You were right about having to import the Models. I imported them into my main.py with the line `from app.models import user`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, seem you are missing the if statement

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Database is still empty when running.